# How to add PDFs to a draft envelope with "transformPdfFields": "true", so that DS assigns the tabs to the existing envelope recipients?

Tags: docusignapi

The customer wants to add multiple documents to an envelope. We need to add the documents one at a time due to their large size. The PDFs have Adobe fields in them

•   We create a draft envelope with 2 signers

•   We then use `PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents` for the PDF documents with `"transformPdfFields": "true"`, but on transformation, DocuSign is creating new recipients as the placeholder recipients. The pdf fields are getting assigned to the placeholder recipients.

•   Problem: we want to use the recipients already present in the draft envelope. 
•   Is there a way to add a document to a draft envelope with "transformPdfFields": "true", so that DocuSign assigns the new tabs to the recipients already present in the draft envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During addition of the document. the transformed fields cannot be assigned to an existing recipient.

However you can make additional calls and reassign the tabs.

1. Get all the recipients and tabs using the [listEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) api. Specify the `include_tabs = true` query string parameter.

   - From the above call get all the Tab ID's that were created from the Transformed Fields.
     Also note the RecipientId of the main recipient and Placeholder recipient.
2. Use the [UpdateEnvelopeRecipientTabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update/) api to reassign the recipients.

   > PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

RecipientId should be that of the main recipient to whom you want to assign the transformed fields.

Json Request

```
{
    "textTabs": [
      {
        "tabId": "1c8ff655-d8c3-4354-b4f2-0bbc4ed73148"
      },
      {
        "tabId": "b861f00e-7f08-4e2f-ab67-c7ea36641aae"
      }
    ]
}
```

3. Delete the place holder recipient that was created during the addition of the document using the [DeleteEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/delete/) api.

   > DELETE /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}

Comment: I have already tried this solution but this is slow in performance. If I am adding lets say 50 documents (each document 200 KB) then complete process is taking almost 3 minutes.

Comment: Even listEnvelopeRecipients api with include_tabs = true is also slow

Comment: Are your documents static or change per envelope? If they are static you can use Templates, so that you don't have to upload them every time. Yes uploading 50 documents will be slow. You will have to rethink your use case rather than uploading 50 documents per envelope.

Comment: `Even listEnvelopeRecipients api with include_tabs = true is also slow` How many tabs does your envelope contain? It should not be slow.

Comment: Documents are not static, a user can upload any document for that case either from his local machine or can select the documents from our app, so template is not a solution. And there is no limit on the tabs, I just checked one document and it has 60 tabs.

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you have large documents. What size are you talking about?